# Visual Studio Simulink connection

Tags: c#, simulink

Is it possible to connect Visual Studio code (say C#) with Simulink model in order to dynamically change input to the model.
I have done some googling but no results.
I'd apprecite any links or step-by-step approach.

Regards

Pete

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean to interface with Simulink during desktop simulation, rather than code generated from a model using Simulink Coder, then you'll need to connect your C# code to MATLAB, and then use MATLAB to interface with Simulink.

You'll most likely want to use the [COM API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html) to connect to MATLAB, then use various of the [MATLAB-Simulink API functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/functionlist.html) to modify the model, particularly `set_param`.

There's a short example of using the API functions [here](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-creating-using-matlab-code.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and path to explore... Do You by chance have any working example of how this connection might look like

Comment: Under the COM API link given above there is an example of calling MATLAB from C#.  Under the other links there are examples of using set_param (and other Simulink functions).